# Strange performance difference in update query alternatives in mariadb

Tags: query-performance, update, mariadb-10.3

We have a table with composite primary key with 1.6M rows where 2 different ways of writing the same query yields vastly different response times.
Unfortunately our ORM creates the slow quiry variant.
Any ideas how to make the `where ... in` variant quicker ?

```sql
update `rsa`.`patient` set `birth` = '20001102' where (`dossier`, `doc1`) in (('10279478', 'IX4')); [2073 ms]
update `rsa`.`patient` set `birth` = '20001102' where `dossier` = '10279478' and `doc1`= 'IX4'; [3 ms]
```

Here's the table definition for reference

```sql
-- rsa.patient definition

CREATE TABLE `patient` (
  `dossier` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `rrn` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmname` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fname` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sex` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `birth` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `address` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `zip` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `city` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `doc1` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `doc2` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `doc3` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Viewed` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `owner` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `species` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `animal` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `cmowner` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ziekenfonds` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `kg1` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `kg2` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `werkgever` varchar(17) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `werknemer` varchar(17) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `chipnr` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ebox` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `doccle` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updatedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `deletedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `declaredToCozoAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cozoDeclarationLastResult` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dossier`,`doc1`),
  KEY `name` (`name`,`fname`),
  KEY `cmname` (`cmname`),
  KEY `cmowner` (`cmowner`),
  KEY `rrn` (`rrn`),
  KEY `doc1` (`doc1`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `doc2` (`doc2`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `doc3` (`doc3`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `patient_createdAt_IDX` (`createdAt`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `patient_updatedAt_IDX` (`updatedAt`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `patient_deletedAt_IDX` (`deletedAt`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `patient_declaredToCozoAt_IDX` (`declaredToCozoAt`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `patient_animal_IDX` (`animal`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```